# Magnific-popup closed when I click on arrows (right/left)

Tags: jquery, css, magnific-popup

I'm using [magnific-popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) plugin for gallery, and I changed the default arrows style using arrows from [fonts-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) font,  but after open the gallery and start clicking on right/left arrows, in specific area the popup closed .. here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/ddarryom/) demo

```
$('.related-gallery').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            gallery:{
                enabled:true,
                arrowMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-arrow custom-mfp-arrow-%dir%"><i class="fa fa-angle-%dir% fa-4x"></i></button>'
            },
            zoom: {
                enabled: true, // By default it's false, so don't forget to enable it

                duration: 300, // duration of the effect, in milliseconds
                easing: 'ease-in-out', // CSS transition easing function 

                // The "opener" function should return the element from which popup will be zoomed in
                // and to which popup will be scaled down
                // By defailt it looks for an image tag:
                opener: function(openerElement) {
                  // openerElement is the element on which popup was initialized, in this case its <a> tag
                  // you don't need to add "opener" option if this code matches your needs, it's defailt one.
                  return openerElement.is('img') ? openerElement : openerElement.find('img');
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in the configuration:

`closeOnBgClick: false`

Comment: Its worked but disabled close on click anywhere out of image .. but it's not the big problem ! thank you

Comment: Btw, just so you know, your fiddle works fine on my end. Clicking the arrows doesn't close the popup. There are just instances that you would accidentally click the bg hence closing the popup.

Comment: that's right, I thought that at first but after I add background color to the arrow holder (button), and click on the button it self not out of it, the problem still there http://jsfiddle.net/fayekramzy/ddarryom/1/ , the problem caused when i click on some positions around the icon ..

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this by adding the **mfp-prevent-close** class to my  FontAwesome icon.

So, your arrowMarkup setting in the gallery would be:

`arrowMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-arrow custom-mfp-arrow-%dir%"><i class="fa fa-angle-%dir% fa-4x mfp-prevent-close"></i></button>'`

Without the class, it reads the custom arrow's click as a background click - which is why DigitalDouble's solution of disabling background clicks to close the gallery worked. You'll notice that even when the gallery was closing, it briefly showed the next image. So the navigation was still working properly, it just had the extra action of closing the gallery too :)

Comment: This worked for me thank you - also using FontAwesome for left and right arrows :-)

Comment: The right class is **mfp-prevent-close** as your example, and not as your top description :)

Comment: Good catch, thanks! I've edited my answer so that the class is correct in both places.

Comment: Didn't work for me for Font Awesome 5. Added css `pointer-events: none` to `.mfp-arrow svg` to prevent the inside svg element from registering the click. The button element handles that anyway.

Comment: used SVG with polyline instead of the Font Awesome and it worked with mfp-prevent-close added to the polyline element